# User Bundle on Symfony 2.2

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, symfony-2.2

I tried to install the FOSUserBundle on Symfony 2.2 without any success.
I followed all the steps described [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) 
but always getting this error :

> MappingException: The class 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces FOS\UserBundle\Entity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have missed out step 5 in the article. Where you have to change the user_class based on your bundle configuration where you have to create a user entity similar to step 3 in the https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md